# How to handle Refresh and Reset in WPF application in MVP application

Tags: wpf, button

I am developing an windows UI application in WPF with MVP architecture with C#.

The application will interact to sqlserver and displays the data to the user.

I have 2 buttons REFRESH and RESET. which refreshes the page and resets the page to the home page respectively.

As I searched in few forums,navigationservice is recommeneded,but I couldnt see navigationservice.refresh() command

Refresh should refresh the page (current page) and the reset should reset to the homepage as per my appication.

Please help me in doing this.
Thanks
Ramm

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom commands for each of your buttons.  The RefreshCommand can reload the data bound to your view, and you can use the ResetCommand to call the NavigationService to navigate to your home page.